# Per-page orientation in a WPF FixedDocument

Tags: wpf, printing, orientation

When printing from WPF using the PrintDialog, you can only set a default page orientation for all pages to print. I'm using a FixedDocument and create multiple pages for different content that I layout myself, including header and footer line. Some of these pages must be landscape, others portrait.

How can I set the orientation for a single page? The FixedPage class doesn't provide such a property.

Comment: Good question. I would like to know it myself.

Answer (score -1):

What about using PrintTicket?

> A PrintTicket object is an easy-to-work-with representation of a
>   certain type of XML document called a PrintTicket document. The latter
>   is a set of instructions telling a printer how to set its various
>   features (such as duplexing, collating, and stapling).

I do not have a clear view of it yet but here it seems to be possible to change page's orientation one by one:

```
// Use different PrintTickets for different FixedDocuments.
PrintTicket ptFD = new PrintTicket();

if (_firstDocumentPrintTicket <= 1)
{   // Print the first document in black/white and in portrait 
    // orientation.  Since the PrintTicket at the 
    // FixedDocumentSequence level already specifies portrait 
    // orientation, this FixedDocument can just inherit that 
    // setting without having to set it again.
    ptFD.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
    ptFD.OutputColor = OutputColor.Monochrome;
    _firstDocumentPrintTicket++;
}

else // if (_firstDocumentPrintTicket > 1)
{   // Print the second document in color and in landscape 
    // orientation.  Since the PrintTicket at the 
    // FixedDocumentSequence level already specifies portrait 
    // orientation, this FixedDocument needs to set its 
    // PrintTicket with landscape orientation in order to 
    // override the higher level setting.
    ptFD.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
    ptFD.OutputColor = OutputColor.Color;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.pageorientation.aspx

Comment: Every PrintTicket will cause a new print job. Every job will be written in its own file when printing to a software printer like PDF. So creating a new PrintTicket will create multiple PDF files, which is not acceptable in my situation. I need different orientations within a single document so that it can be printed as one.

Comment: I agree that multiple PDF files instead of one are not acceptable. Thanks for clearing it up. I leave my answer as a lesson how not to do it ;)